# Getting error during synchronizing on \Unicorn.aspx

Tags: sitecore-client, unicorn

With Sitecore project codebase and successfully following all the gulpfile.js steps for deployment, I visited \unicorn.aspx page and getting error while synchronizing projects.

Error is refering to some missing serialization provider.

[image]

Comment: The screenshot is nearly impossible to read. Please copy the text into a formatted block to help. From what I can see it means that your folder containing the yml files does not have an item matching what's listed. When this happens it means files in the database will be moved to the recycle bin.

Comment: @MichaelWest: It is referring to the missing serialization provider. Also you can click on the image you will get the details

Comment: You are right, yml file does not have all the items from sitecore. Actually I just started looking into sitecore project for the first time and learning on this. I want to restore sitecore instance on my local machine, I only have project codebase and I am wondering do I need core and master database backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an error.  It is a warning letting you know that you have an item in Sitecore that you don't have YML for and it has deleted the item from Sitecore.  This may be expected behavior if the item is supposed to be deleted.  If you aren't expecting the item to be deleted you'll need to look into if you have the latest YML and add it back to your folder or restore the item and reserialize if what you have in Sitecore is the latest and you need to update the YML on disk.

Comment: I have never worked in sitecore and this the first time I am working on sitecore project. I have received a project code base  which is structured in helix and I have executed all the gulp file steps. Is it possible to get all the missing files. Do I need database backup along with codebase?

Comment: We are having a running instance on some server and I am trying to setup sitecore instance on my local machine.